# Clear All Filter button not clears value of date filter in Ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid-react

We are using react Ag-Grid date filter. We implementated it as given in documentation, below is the link, which we referenced:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-date/

Also we are using custom Date component 
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-date-component/

We have a button for clearing all filters, where we are using grip api as
this.gridApi.setFilterModel();

Our problem is,
when we click on clear all filter button, it does not clears date filter values that added while filtering, but if I click second time, those values are cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem as well, in a **Custom Filter** that was linked to a **Custom Floating Filter**.  What fixed it for me was to trigger the **filterChangedCallback** in the **setModel** method in the parent Custom Filter, after updating the filter's value in the state.  You can use the setState callback parameter to achieve this in a class build, or useState hook in a functional build.

The reasoning is that after the api sets the Custom Filter model to null by calling the implementation of *setModel*, you need to notify the grid and any dependents, such as you would on a regular change event.

```
setModel(model) {
    this.setState({ selectedValue: model }, () => { this.props.filterChangedCallback() })
}
```

See the [Filter Component Interface (IFilterComp) in the documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/) for further details.